# MySQL - How to store inputs of unknown & varying size?

Tags: mysql, sql

All,

I am trying to create a table to receive user inputs (UGC).  This content could vary in size from a single character up to a few hundred words.  The input will be coded in `utf8_unicode_ci` and could be in Latin or multi-byte characters.

The input will have to be searchable.

(Longer term I might want to store non-text objects - pictures and the like, but for now let's focus on UTF8 text.)

At this point, I am only envisioning 2 fields to this table: an ID (autoincrement `INT(10)` ) and the UGC itself.  (I might need a few more fields like `dateAdded`, etc.)

How should I structure my DB to allow for a good compromise between flexibility and performance?  I could...

1. Set up a high limit on the size of the string and take the performance & usability hits.
2. Create several tables for various size ranges (and eventually types), and identify each item by a combination of table name and ID (so I'd need a central table with unique ID, table name, table-specific ID).
3. I could store each object separately and simply have the db store a url.  I suspect that ends up being a less efficient version of #2, but I'm out of my depth.

Thank you,

JDelage

Comment: Is any part of this UGC considered searchable?

Comment: @Eugen Rieck - Yes, good point.  I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good rule of thumb - and as all rules of thumb it is far from perfect - that has been working quite well for me:

- If the DB "understands" the content of a potentially BLOBy field, store it in the DB
- If the DB has no understanding of the content, store it externally

With this and my experience so far in mind, I discourage use of a BLOB field for images etc.

Now when thinking of content, that can be text, image or whatever, I am quite sure your business logic will need some field, that tells it how to use the content of the big field anyway - it's hard to think of an app that would treat an image as an image just after looking at the data. So I recommend you create such a field, `mimetype` would come to mind, and a, say, `mediumtext` field. Your app business logic could easily deduce, that `mimetype='text/plain'` would mean the data in the text field is the payload, while `mimetype='image/png'` would mean, that the data in the text field is the (relative) path to a file resource.

This gives you searching and indexing on the content, with quite a low probability of false matches, if you create your file pathes in a way, that is not expected to be a word in any language. `MD5(basename).suffix` comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

Since you also mentioned about storing picture and non-text it is recommended to use BLOB type. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html

If this table is content-heavy using the URL approach with a CDN might be effective as well, but obviously you are dealing with extra cost and some programming effort to deal with CDN.

Answer (score 1):

For some aspects of what you're looking at a varchar seems like the best option but when it comes to storing pictures or binary objects it won't be so good, unless you're storing it on the file system and using the field to save the path to the object.   Otherwise you may need to use a varchar and a blob field.